# Remove the paragraph tags from iFrames in php

Tags: php

When I use a Iframe from Youtube/Facebook it surrounds by paragraph tag and dont want the Iframe to be surrounded by html paragraph tag. How can I remove this paragraph tag before and after the Iframe?

(Used custom PHP framework made by the Company)

After embedding the Iframe output in the browser -

```html
<p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_GuOjXYl5ew" allowfullscreen="" width="700" height="415" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
```

I need the output to be like this -

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_GuOjXYl5ew" allowfullscreen="" width="700" height="415" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have enough information. Please explain more about the BBCODE that your CMS using, moreover- it will help a lot if you add the file\s that getting the data from DB.

Anyway, you should to do something like this:

```
function remove_p_tag($content) {
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks . This code works @ramirez

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
strip_tags($input, '<p></p>');
```